# Как хранятся свойства объекта kotlin в памяти и сам объект?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, heap

В java у класса есть поля, в kotlin свойства и теневые поля у этого свойства, как хранятся в памяти эти свойства, как ссылки? Как выглядит экземпляр объекта в памяти?

Comment: Так же как и в Java. Свойство есть поле + автоматически сгенерированные геттер и сеттер (если свойство не read-only).

Comment: [What are the differences between Kotlin class properties and Java class fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719542)